# How to create custom breakpoints with Material UI without changing theme?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I had a question regarding breakpoints when dealing with responsiveness. I'm using Material UI, which has breakpoints at which you can enable different CSS styles. These are predefined, like xs, xl, md, etc.. I want to set breakpoints at custom pixel values. Is there any way to do this easily within a component without modifying theme?

If this can't be done, what is a good alternative without changing the theme?

Answer (score 0):

you can create another theme with the same values of the previous one **if needed** but with the updated `breakpoints` property and use it wherever you want you just have to wrapp what you want within it for example:

```js
const newTheme = createMuiTheme({
  //...
  breakpoints: {
    // update
  },
});
```

dont forget to import `createMuiTheme` and `ThemeProvider` from mui.

```
<ThemeProvider theme={newTheme}>
     <div>..</div>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two approaches for custom breakpoints without changing the MUI theme.

- **Pass an inline breakpoint value. e.g.**

  ```
  import Box from '@mui/material/Box'

  <Box maxWidth={600}>
    ...
  </Box>
  ```

- **Create a reusable custom breakpoint object. e.g.**

  ```
  import Box from '@mui/material/Box'

  const customBreakPoints = {
    A: 0,
    B: 600,
    C: 1200,
    D: 1500,
  }

  <Box maxWidth={customBreakPoints.B}>
         ...
  </Box>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

More complete example of mixing a theme in for a custom theme around a component:

```
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const breakpointOverrides = {
  xs: 0,
  sm: 600,
  md: 900,
  lg: 1200,
  xl: 1440
};

const getCustomTheme = (theme) =>
  createTheme({
    ...theme,
    breakpoints: { values: { ...breakpointOverrides } }
  });

// and around your component:
export const FooPonent = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={getCustomTheme(theme)}>
      <>My Component w/ mixed-in theme</>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

More in the docs:
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/

Another approach is in using `styled`:

```
// Grid could be box or whatever you want for layout...
const BreakpointWrapper = styled(Grid)(({ theme }) => ({
  [theme.breakpoints.up('xs')]: {
    width: '100%',
    background: 'yellow'
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    maxWidth: '600px'
    width: '100%',
    background: 'orange'
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
    maxWidth: '900px',
    width: '100%',
    background: 'red'
  },
  // ...etcetera
}));

export const WithBreakpointWrapper = (props) => {
  return (
    <BreakpointWrapper>
      <Box {...props}>Hello Werld</Box>
    </BreakpointWrapper>
  );
};
```